# how to config laravel dynamic email sender

Tags: laravel, email, environment-variables

my code already can for sending an email. but the issue is in sender's email name. how to make it dynamic based on user input.

My Controller:

```
class contactUsController extends Controller{
function index(Request $req){
    $this->validate($req,
    [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'message'=>'min:10'
    ]);

    $email = $req->input('email');
    $messages = $req->input('message');

    $data = array(
        'email' => $email,
        'bodyMessage' => $messages 
    );


    Mail::send('Email.emailsendcontact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
        $message->to('noticemyartheaddivision@gmail.com');
        $message->from($data['email']);   
        $message->subject('NoticeMyArt Customer Service');
    });
    return redirect('home');
}}
```

My Env.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=noticemyartheaddivision@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD='my Password'
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

My mail.php

```
    'from' => [
    'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
    'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Second parameter of `from` method in Laravel `Mailable` class is `name`. See [this](https://github.com/illuminate/mail/blob/master/Mailable.php#L403).

```
// Illuminate\Mail\Mailable

/**
 * Set the sender of the message.
 *
 * @param  object|array|string  $address
 * @param  string|null  $name
 * @return $this
 */
public function from($address, $name = null)
{
    return $this->setAddress($address, $name, 'from');
}
```

So you can set the sender name and sender email with:

```
$message->from('some.email@here.com', 'Put Your Name Here');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Have you try to restart your queue listener?

Comment: i dont use queue listener. i just following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=09rshFmGwc0&t=259s